# Calculate average latitude and longitude in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, latitude-longitude, average

I have (minLatitude,maxLatitude) and (minLongitude,maxLongitude) pairs in decimal degrees, and I need to calculate the mean point of the box those pairs define, how can I get their average latitude/longitude? I get a pretty big offset when the simple arithmetic mean is calculated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, how are you calculating "the simple arithmetic mean"?

Comment: @Yuck, the world is round, not flat

Comment: And what do you mean by "pretty big offset"? Are you expecting the great circle distance to be equal to all four corners of your bounding box?

Comment: @Yuck: like always, just (lat + lon) / 2

Comment: @Henk - Do you mean `(lat1 + lat2) / 2`

Comment: I did as Oded said, just to check if that solution could give me a good enough measure, but when drawing the point in Google Earth, I see that the point is quite far away from the one that should be aproximately the center

Comment: I read somewhere that the arithmetic mean approach works quite well for small distances, but I need it to be more accurate for large distances as well

Comment: @Evens: And how did you find/determine that reference point?

Comment: MIght help if you edit in your example, along with wha you think the result *should* be

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give you a particular example of what the result should be because I'm just checking if the result I get looks fine in Google Earth... The latitude-longitud box I talked about is actually a polygon that is drawn in a map layer and I need to set an icon more or less over its center :S

Answer (score 8):

The solution suggested by Pierre-Luc Champigny is wrong.

In the image bellow you can see two lines:

1. (lat1,lon1) --> (lat2,lon2)
2. (lat1,lon2) --> (lat2,lon1)

Half length of each line in green, the other half in blue.

You can see that the center of both lines is not the same point, and both centers are not the center of the polygon.

[image: earth]

In order to find the center of the polygon:

- lat= avrg(lat1,lat2)
- lon= avrg(lon1,lon2)

To get these values you can use the link suggested by Pierre-Luc Champigny, but:

- Take the lat of the midpoint of (lat1,lon1) --> (lat2,lon1)
- Take the lon of the midpoint of (lat1,lon1) --> (lat1,lon2)

Answer (score 5):

From: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Your values should be all in radian, so using the midpoint formula:

```
var lat1 = minLatitude;  // In radian
var lat2 = maxLatitude;  // In radian
var lon1 = minLongitude; // In radian
var lon2 = maxLongitude; // In radian

var dLon = (lon2-lon1); 


var Bx = Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Cos(dLon);
var By = Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Sin(dLon);
var avgLat = Math.Atan2(
           Math.Sin(lat1) + 
           Math.Sin(lat2), 
           Math.Sqrt((
           Math.Cos(lat1)+Bx) * (Math.Cos(lat1)+Bx) + By*By));

var avgLong = lon1 + Math.Atan2(By, Math.Cos(lat1) + Bx);
```

Comment: Thanks, Pierre-Luc. I tried your code snippet and the average longitude seems to be coherent but the average latitude doesn't, I get a really tiny value...

Comment: Did you try to enter your values into the calculator on the website ?

Comment: The avgLat and avgLon return RADIANS not degrees.   And lon1 should be in radians.

Comment: @Evenstar did you finally solved your problem? If you solved it with my answer, could you mark it as the solution?